# Powershell cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest chokes on wildcard?

Tags: powershell, wildcard, webrequest

Weirdness: I have a Powershell  cmdlet here that seems for all the world to be choking on a wildcard character. I didn't know that was possible, to be honest--I mean, this thing says it doesn't actually *accept* wildcards, so whatever...

Anyway, this is a script that downloads files from a series of webpages. One of them in the middle, instead of having a static link, has a link more like... "http://foo.org/file.php?filestuff", and every time I get to that one file, I get this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path http://foo.org/file.php?filestuff did not resolve to a file.
```

How do I get around that?

Comment: Looks like it might actually be a problem with the request being denied--which seems to imply that the error message is actually in error rather than the cmdlet, huh?

Comment: In that case the web application would be at fault for not returning a proper status code. I just ran some quick tests and the cmdlet reported the appropriate errors.

Comment: This smells more like you're not using the correct parameters. You should be passing the address to the `-Uri` parameter of `invoke-webrequest`. Can you show your invocation syntax?

Comment: please show the invocation syntax like @x0n specified. Also, does the path include an asterix or something? Not familiar with a "wildcard path", especially in http-uri

Comment: Yah, and check it for Obelixes too! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix ;-) In all seriousness, there is no such thing as wildcard paths in the http protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the request was actually being denied by the website and, as a result, the cmdlet was returning that nonsense about wildcard paths. I *think* that's because the path did, in fact, include a *powershell* wildcard (that is, the ? -- which is definitely legal in an HTTP request, believe it or not :P).